# Переопределение окружения enumerate

Tags: latex

Необходимо переопределить окружение enumerate так, чтобы нумерация производилась римскими цифрами, а элементы перечня - кружочками

Как-то так:

```
1. Что-то первое
2. Что-то второе
  ○ Что-то первое второго
  ○ Что-то второе второго
3. Что-то третье
```

Comment: Это арабские цифры, а не римские. Вообще, это обычная штатная замена маркеров в списках, а не "переопределение" окружения. Описана в любом приличном учебнике по LaTeX.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/lists#Nested_Lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно именно римскими цифрами, то делается как в примере ниже. Если нужно арабскими, то можно просто закомментировать две строки для переопределения маркера нумерованного списка, так как такой стиль для нумерованных списков первого уровня идет по умолчанию. Либо можно раскомментировать строку: `\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}` и закомментировать `\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Roman{enumi}}` соответственно.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\circ$} % переопределение маркера для маркированного списка

%\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Roman{enumi}} % задаем стиль для счетчика нумерованного списка 1-го уровня в виде римских цифр
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi.} % формируем маркер для нумерованного списка 1-го уровня с использованием модифицированного вышк счетчика

\begin{enumerate}\itemsep=-5pt
    \item Что-то первое
    \item Что-то второе
    \begin{itemize}\itemsep=-5pt
        \item Что-то первое второго
        \item Что-то второе второго
    \end{itemize} 
    \item пункт
    \item пункт
\end{enumerate}    

\end{document}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]